# Deploying Kubeflow pipelines using cli or API, not on UI

Tags: pipeline, kubeflow

Kubeflow pipelines can be created by uploading on the pipelines UI.

But it's annoying to develop pipelines, repeating some changes and uploading again.

There seems to be no related documents.

Is it possible to deploy Kubeflow pipelines using cli or API, not on UI?

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an [example notebook](https://github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/blob/cab950c06345b97a702a2891e61d3bb626c59710/samples/notebooks/Lightweight%20Python%20components%20-%20basics.ipynb).

At the bottom of the notebook, Kubeflow pipelines can be run on code using Kubeflow pipeline python sdk.

Answer (score 0):

You can submit pipeline for execution using `kfp.Client(host=...).create_run_from_pipeline_func(my_pipeline, arguments={})`